# How can I retrieve XML data from \Yii::$app->request?

Tags: xml, yii2, request

I subscribed api action to cloudpbx.beeline.ru events. So when event occurs beeline sends request to my action as XML. I'm sure about that because when I do  \Yii::$app->request->getContentType() it returns application/xml; charset=UTF-8. But I have no idea what to do next. I tried to get $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, \Yii::$app-request->getRawData everything is empty. 
Yii documentations has no proper methods in request object to work with XML.
Please help.

Comment: The `rawBody` property should be what you are looking for. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$rawBody-detail

Comment: Thank you Michal Hynčica. Actually it is. I just didn't know that rawBody is a string a tried to convert it with json_encode() that returned an empty array. It was so stupid)